# GUI layout algorithms overview

Tags: algorithm, layout

I'm looking for systematic review of the algorithms used for GUI layout. I'm particularly interested in the algorithms that favor speed over complexity, but it's hard to find anything useful other than "don't use constraint sovers".

So far the best one I've found is Constraint Solving for Beautiful User Interfaces: How Solving Strategies Support Layout Aesthetics by Clemens Zeidler,Christof Lutteroth and Gerald Weber. Unfortunately it is very short  and is not very specific.

The layout algorithm landscape looks to me like this so far:

- There's everybody's darling Cassowary that made its way just about everywhere.
- There's the Auckland Layout Model which no one seems to use but thanks to its authors being prolific writers is well known.
- There's the universally hated HTML/CSS combo that completely destroys the former two when it comes to the flow layout (especially the text flow).
- Next come the algorithms used in desktop GUI frameworks, with WPF, Qt and MigLayout for Swing lauded the most. (I haven't figured out their performance characteristics yet, but I remember being disappointed by WPF layout speed compared to WinForms - the gains from faster drawing were offset by slower layout)
- Than there's a handful of game engines UIs that no one seems to know anything about.
- The rest are the ancient GUI toolkits that typically have an unsophisticated  grid container as their most potent layout tool.

Have I missed anything significant?

Comment: I think most of the original ideas around algorithmic layout come from TeX, which is certainly worth a mention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX

Comment: I don't know of any overviews per se, but Flutter has quite extensive documentation on their layout algorithms and the design choices behind them: see https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview#rendering-and-layout and https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/inside-flutter

WPF, which is fairly similar, also has some decent documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/layout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: The ORC Solver repository contains 4 different algorithms ORCSolver, Pure Z3, QP for Flows, Pure Branch & Bound. Project: https://yuejiang-nj.github.io/papers/CHI2020_ORCSolver/project_page.html | Github:  https://github.com/YueJiang-nj/ORCSolver-CHI2020/